# Mesa: Howto enable OpenGL 3.x functionality via extensions?

Tags: opengl, c++

How can I enable OpenGL 3.x functionality via extensions? I'm new to OpenGL development under Linux. Currently I have:

```
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
#include <GL/osmesa.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
```

My problem with Mesa and OpenGL 2.x is that I get an OpenGL "invalid value" error here:

```
glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F_ARB, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL );
```

because of `GL_RGBA32F_ARB`, it seems.

Background: I need the texture for a framebuffer object, and `GL_RGBA32F_ARB` for float data without clamping. My program works well using OpenGL 3.0 if I create the context with GLX.

Comment: If you can share a complete but minimal example I'm interested in investigating.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's better to use GLEW to export all the extensions functionality. It's cross platform and allows you to write conditional code for different configurations.

Comment: I tried glew now:   

    #include <GL/glew.h>
    #ifndef GLAPI
    #define GLAPI extern
    #endif
    #include <GL/osmesa.h>
    #include <GL/glu.h> |

I have to (re-)define GLAPI because glew undefines it at the end of the header and gl.h it not included again in the osmesa.h. I found that in a forum post.   |   

Result: still not successfull with GL_RGBA32F_ARB. Additionally, my shaders now do not compile successfully.

If relevant: I have Debian Wheezy with Mesa 8.0.5 and Glew 1.7.

Comment: Have you initialized glew as shows glew's homepage?

Comment: I did. I already use glew for the windows version of my application. I just removed the #ifdef WIN32 line(s). I can recheck on monday if there is something different on linux.

Comment: According to the glew homepage, there is no difference between windows and linux. So glew initialization/usage should not be the problem. :(

Comment: glew isn't compatible with osmesa because glew incorrectly assumes that OpenGL is a part of X Windows and uses functions from GLX and those don't work with OSMesa contexts.